# Finding probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A random sample of size $n = 1460$ is obtained from a population whose size is $N = 1,500,000$ and whose population proportion with a specified characteristic is $p = 0.42$. What is the probability of obtaining $x = 657$ or more individuals with the particular characteristic? (You can assume all assumptions hold including normality.)

Answer (score 1):

$N$ is only there to establish the validity of the normal approximation

use
$$\mu=np \text{ and } \sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$$
to calculate
$$Z_{657}=\frac{657-\mu}{\sigma}$$
then look up $P(Z>Z_{657})$ in a standard normal distribution table.